# Building forecast Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in Pandas that contains forecasted sales data that looks like this:

```
   | Date  | ProductID | Forecasted_Date | Sales |
---|-------|-----------|-----------------|-------|
 0 | 1_Jan | 1         | 2_Jan           | 10    |
 1 | 1_Jan | 2         | 3_Jan           | 3     |
 2 | 1_Jan | 1         | 2_Jan           | 7     |
 3 | ...   |           |                 |       |
 4 | 2_Jan | 1         | 3_Jan           | 7     |
```

On each Date, and for each ProductId, sales are forecasted between 1 and 20 days in front (the Forecasted_date).

I want to create a new DataFrame, MultiIndexed by "[Date, ProductID]" and with the following columns:

```
| IND_Date | IND_ProductID | F1 | F2   | ... | F20 |
|----------|---------------|----|------|-----|-----|
| 1_Jan    | 1             | 10 | 3    |     |     |
| 1_Jan    | 2             | 7  | etc. |     |     |
| ...      |               |    |      |     |     |
| 2_Jan    | 1             | 7  |      |     |     |
```

Where the columns represent the number of days ahead the forecast was made. (I.e., for Date=1_Jan, F1=Sales on 2_Jan).

What is the best way to construct this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

If `df` is my base dataframe...

1. Find difference in days, assuming Date and Forecasted_Date are in Datetime format:

```
df['difference'] = (df['Forecasted_Date'] - df['Date']) / pd.Timedelta(1,'D'))
```

2. Convert to required "f_" format:

```
df['forecast_day'] = 'f_' + df['difference'].astype('int').astype('str')
```

3. Create pivot table

```
df_forecast = pd.pivot_table(data=df, values="Sales", index=["Date", "Product_ID"], columns="forecast_day", aggfunc="sum")
```

Done!